# How to Sum with limits (google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

**Background**:

I have an odd issue with Google sheets, I have a bunch of tournament results lets say

Team 1 comes 1st at 10 events, 2nd at 3 events and, 3rd at 8 events.

I need to take only their top 15 events which in this case would be:
1st - 10 times
2nd - 3 times
3rd - 2 times

Then this needs to be applied to a large number of teams (around 100) and a lot of events

**My Current Solution**:

Currently I have a solution for tracking all total results for a given team

```
=sumif("first_place","team name","all total results")" I then repeat this formula for each column of results e.g. "=sumif("second_place","team name","all total results")","=sumif("third_place","team name","all total results")
```

**Problem (need advice)**:
however I am not sure how to limit this to only their top X results across all events.

**update**

I've settle on this formula as a temporary solution

```
=If(COUNTIF(Team_position,H2)< 6,Sumif(Team_position,Team_Name,team_points),"Team has played more than 6 events")
```

It simply gives me an error once a team plays more than the required number of events

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: can you show an example of the data and expected output.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output